# How to fix 'Can not connect to MySQL server' error?

Tags: mysql

First of all I apologize for my English is not perfect.

I'm trying to connect to mysql database remotely.

I have already done the basic steps such as, for example, comment the bind address in `my.cnf`.

I gave permissions to the appropriate users in MySQL.

I tried with my friend to do it connect to the database, and it worked but we were in the same room with the same router.

Now I'm home and I tried to connect my friend, but I always get error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can not connect to MySQL server ....
```

Maybe it's a problem of my home router? I can not even do the telnet.

P.S. I've also taken steps to set the firewall.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Seriously, in general be more precise what you did, post the statements you issued, the complete error message and so on.

Comment: have you checked pinging your friend system?

Comment: sorry if I was not precise 
the mysql db is on a virtual machine Lubuntu virtual machine is located on a PC windows8 

I set the windows firewall rule that says that any incoming requests from any IP address on port 3306 must be turned over to the virtual machine which has static ip. 

I have done so: 
- Removed the ip of my machine using a utility on the web 
- Tried to telnet ip 3306 but I got a time out error 

obviously it did not work either mysql-u admin-p-h 1xx.xx.xx.xx-P3306

Comment: is the MySQL server hosted on a machine with public IP?  
Or at lest an IP that can be accessed from your router?

Comment: the mysql server is on a virtual machine with a static ip. 

I connect to the physical machine via ip then do I have to forward to the virtual machine. The forward is managed by a nat virtual (vmware)

Comment: @bomberdini yes it happens with me also because ...in my MySql server there is one security that allow IP address for access database..

So I think this kind of problem you are facing ....If you are using Cpenal then go to detabase section and put your Ip address in to allow remote access section and you will be able to connect

Comment: hello @ChintanGor and thanks for the reply. I did not understand the solution you propose, you could explain. thanks

Comment: @bomberdini ...First let me know that are you using nay C-PENAL or not?

Comment: @bomberdini ...In my case I am using shared Hosting server and they have some ristriction of IP that my database connection work only with Localhot ......or 127.0.0.1 if I want to Put my Code on another server(application server) then I need to add aplication server's IP address in "Remote Database Access Hosts "

Example:
 Suppose my Current IP is '78.XX.XX.Xx' and i want to access remote database from my machine then I need to add this IP '78.XX.XX.Xx' in "Remote Database Access Hosts " using C-penel detail

Comment: @ChintanGor hello and thanks for the reply. 
I do not know C-penal But if you give me some information I can use it

Comment: @bomberdini this is the link how to add remote IP to cpenel

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=xXOq9U9fzOo

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

this is the Example how to put exeption of your IP address over DATABASE server settings.....please check this if you have server FULL access of contact to your Database administrator and ask him to put your IP in this file as allowd

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons for that,

- **mysqld** is not running on the local host. Check your operating
  system's process list to ensure the **mysqld** process is present.
- You're running a MySQL server on Windows with many TCP/IP connections
  to it. If you're experiencing that quite often your clients get that
  error, you can find a workaround here: [**Section B.5.2.2.1, “Connection
  to MySQL Server Failing on Windows”**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html#can-not-connect-to-server-on-windows).
- Check whether the server is running on that host by executing **telnet
  some_host 3306** and pressing the Enter key a couple of times. (3306 is
  the default MySQL port number. Change the value if your server is
  listening to a different port.) If there is a MySQL server running
  and listening to the port, you should get a response that includes
  the server's version number. If you get an error such as **telnet:
  Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused**, then there is
  no server running on the given port.

Look at this mySQL full [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html), it will be helpful.

Comment: I have a question mysql must be run on the virtual machine and not on windows?